# tableToJson is not working when table has one row only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using tableToJson from [here](https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json)

I have the following modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalShopOrder" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Batch</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label class="control-label">Designation:</label>
                    <div id='complaintProgress' style="position: relative;">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DesignationShopOrder" id="DesignationShopOrder">
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="well">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive table-bordered" id="shopOrderTable" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-override="ShopOrderDes">Designation</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">                              
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="addShopOrder();" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And there is the script that I am running to add the item to the table:

```
<script>
    function addShopOrder(){
        var designation = document.getElementById('DesignationShopOrder').value;
        var table = document.getElementById("shopOrderTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        row.hidden = false;
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = designation;

        var shopOrders = $('#shopOrderTable').tableToJSON();
        shopOrders.pop();
        var infoRec = new Array();
        infoRec = JSON.stringify(shopOrders);
        document.getElementById('shopOrderSender').value = infoRec;
    }

</script>
```

I click the button to add, and my tableToJson array is empty!
If I click twice, I get the array with data!

Why I need to click twice? If I have one line in table, I want to convert it too!
There are the images with the firebug details inside the red rectangle!
[image: No Data after first click]

[image: With one element after second click]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probally due to "shopOrders.pop();" you are removing the last item, if you only have one you are removing it